# Is there a radio function for microbit micropython?

Tags: micropython, bbc-microbit

I can't figure out what it is.

```
      from microbit import*
      # what is the words that trigger it?
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. Is it something that isn't explained in the [documentation](https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/radio.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The micro:bit MicroPython documentation for the radio module shows you what's available: https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/radio.html

And the radio tutorial is a good introduction to what it can do: https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/radio.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick demo for radio messaging system between two micro:bits, the first one plays sender role, and the second on is a receiver.

**1st board:**

```
from microbit import *
import radio
radio.config(group=5)
radio.on()

while True:        
    if button_a.is_pressed():
        radio.send('A is pressed')
```

**2nd board:**

```
from microbit import *
import radio
radio.config(group=5)
radio.on()
while True:
    message = radio.receive()
    if message == 'A is pressed':
        display.scroll(message)
```